# Installing perf on old linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, performancecounter

I have linux 2.6.18 running on my servers and would like to use 'perf' subsytem. This kernel version doesn't have perf. So I downloaded latest version linux 2.6.38 and traversed to the /tools/perf/ and installed it.

From command line, I can list the available performance counters. But when I try getting one event's features, it is showing up

"Error: open_counter returned with 38 (Function not implemented). /bin/dmesg may provide  additional information.

Fatal: Not all events could be opened."

Does the old linux kernel support perf. Please suggest how can I get it running given the restriction that I can't update the kernel version on my server.

Comment: Can you install custom compiled kernel on the server (same version but added patches or changed compile options)? What is the distribution of Linux used on server? (redhat/debian/ubuntu/suse and the version)

Answer (score 3):

> Does the old linux kernel support perf.

No, it does not. The performance counters subsystem has undergone significant recent changes, and you are exceedingly unlikely to get perf working on any kernel [below 2.6.31.](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vweaver1/projects/perf-events/)